# Knob.js to move on mouse scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, tween, jquery-knob

Hello and thank you for your time.

I was hoping that someone has already run into this issues and solved it.

I am trying to make the knob.js to move up and down as you scroll on the website and not have to be over the knob for it to move.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
data-readonly="true"
```

So here is the example

```
<input class="knob" value="0" rel="70" data-readonly="true">
```

For more information check http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ "Readonly" example